# MKAnnotationView doesn't show custom pin

Tags: ios5, ios6, mapkit

I'm implementing a custom pin for a map, the image is in te project's folder but didn't show.
Perhaps (and very likely) I'm doing something wrong.

The map displays and shows the pins (default red pins) but not the custom image nor the `UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure`

This is the code I'm using:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{

// in case it's the user location, we already have an annotation, so just return nil
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
{
    return nil;
}
 static NSString *TheAnnotationIdentifier = @"theAnnotationIdentifier";

MKAnnotationView *shoppeAnnotationView =
[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:TheAnnotationIdentifier];
if (shoppeAnnotationView == nil)
{
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:TheAnnotationIdentifier];

    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin.png"];
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [ UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure ];
    annotationView.opaque = NO;

    return annotationView; 
}
    return nil;
}
```

Any hints?

Thank you!

Comment: Put an NSLog or breakpoint at the start of the condition, inside the curly braces after `if (shoppeAnnotationView == nil)`. Is that code ever even running?

Comment: Have you fixed that? I am facing the same problem